# How to update PureScript record defined with `data` instead of `type`?

Tags: purescript

Updating a record defined with `type` works, as explained over at [Differences from Haskell](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Differences-from-Haskell)

```
type PointRec = { x :: Number, y :: Number }

setX :: Number -> PointRec -> PointRec 
setX val point = point { x = val }
```

but when defined with `data` (and thus specifying a constructor), it doesn’t:

```
data PointRec = PointRec { x :: Number, y :: Number }

setX :: Number -> PointRec -> PointRec 
setX val point = point { x = val }
```

The error I get from the compiler is

```
Could not match type
```

and some details.

What can I do here?

Comment: Is using a lens the only solution? (Just found the article on `purescript-lens` in Day 6 of “24 Days…”).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to unwrap and wrap the data constructor:

```
data PointRec = PointRec { x :: Number, y :: Number }

setX :: Number -> PointRec -> PointRec 
setX val (PointRec point) = PointRec (point { x = val })
```

Comment: Makes sense. I’ve been doing the unwrapping elsewhere as per the documentation I found; just didn’t think of wrapping again.